# Bootstrap dropdown sub-menu not appearing correctly in tablet/phone view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I did search through the many bootstrap dropdown questions, but couldn't see any with the same specific problem as myself!

I'm having an issue with the Bootstap Dropdown Navbar sub-menu's...

I'm using the latest release of Bootstrap (v2.0.3)

Everything now appears to be working fine in standard desktop view - but when i shrink the browser width (or view on iPhone/iPad), the sub-menu's are not working correctly.

Best if you just go visit my test site at [TEST SITE](http://pointstest.defade.com/)

As you can see, the "Points Tables" drop down is fine in desktop view, but in 'mobile' view something is wrong. The 'pop up' does not work and the sub-menus are permanently on display.

I believe i have followed the example code exactly (other than figuring out via the 'upgrade doc' that the 'caret' needed to be implemented in a new different way to how the example shows)

Here is my current code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#"><img alt="F1Stockcars.com" src="../assets/img/logo.png"></a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Points Tables
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">National Points</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">World Championship Qualifying</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Track Championships</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Meeting Results</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Drivers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Final Winners</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Top Scorers by Meeting</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Highest Scores</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Back to F1Stockcars.com</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out what i have done wrong, the page started as one of their example pages, so should have all necessary code, and i have added the entire bootstrap framework to my server, even including the javascripts i won't actually be needing.

Any help would be appreciated  as i'm completely baffled by this

I only have very basic skills, so please keep it simple

Many Thanks - Ade

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
```

to:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
```

This solved the problem for me. I picked it up in the example on the bootstrap site at: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar (scroll down to to the Responsive Navbar section).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to include the bootstart-collapse.js?

It should work, if you add it.